# Extracting data from a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data that looks like below-

```
id            a_json
111       {key:A,values:[123,2345,2345,456,78,9]}
222       {key:A,values:[1112, 323, 11, 11]}
```

I want to extract the UNIQUE numbers in the square bracket (values). Following is what I tried-

```
SELECT
  id,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(a_json, r'([0-9]+)*(,[0-9]+)*'),
  a_json
FROM 
`project.dataset.table`
WHERE
  a_json like  "%values%"
GROUP BY
  id,
  a_json
```

But this gives me the following error-

```
Regular expression passed to REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL must not have more than 1 capturing group
```

I want the result to look like-

```
id            a_json                                  numbers
111       {key:A,values:[123,2345,2345,456,78,9]}   123,2345,456,78,9
222       {key:A,values:[1112,323,11,11]}           1112,323,11
```

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use below regexp

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(a_json, r'\d+') as numbers
```

in this case output will be

```
Row id  a_json                              numbers  
1   111 {key:A,values:[123,2345,456,78,9]}  123  
                                            2345     
                                            456  
                                            78   
                                            9    
2   222 {key:A,values:[1112, 323, 11]}      1112     
                                            323  
                                            11
```

As alternative  - you can use below version - in this case you can omit `WHERE a_json like  "%values%"`

```
SPLIT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(a_json, r'values:\[(.*)]')) numbers
```

with exact same output

> I want to see the result in the comma separated format. Also, I forgot to mention in the question that I need to check for unique values while doing this.

Below simple adjustments will do the trick

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 111 id, '{key:A,values:[123,2345,2345,456,78,9]}' a_json UNION ALL
  SELECT 222, '{key:A,values:[1112, 323, 11, 11]}' 
)
SELECT id, a_json,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT number) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(a_json, r'values:\[(.*)]'))) number) numbers
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row id      a_json                                      numbers  
1   111     {key:A,values:[123,2345,2345,456,78,9]}     123,2345,456,78,9    
2   222     {key:A,values:[1112, 323, 11, 11]}          1112, 323, 11
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to see the result in the comma separated format. Also, I forgot to mention in the question that I need to check for unique values while doing this. Updated the question.

Comment: Sure. see update. if you have even more question - please post them as new questions and we will be happy to help. changing already posted question - especially already answered - is not how it works here on SO :o)

Comment: The with clause results in an error. Also, the select query below the with clause results into null value in 'numbers' when there is only one number in 'values' inside a_json.

Comment: with clause is just for you to test. if you run against your real data - just remove it! that simple! as of null for only one number - not true  - i cannot reproduce that at all!!! and BTW, just use the last query as it was added after you "changed/adjusted" your question